# System keeps crashing

Tags: linux, logs, crash

Here is my problem: couple of months ago I was using Arch Linux on my machine, and it went all good for couple of months, until I installed Genymotion that is a software for Android Simulation. Basically what happens since then is that the system randomly crashes now and then (sometimes after just couple of minutes, sometimes it can last 1-2 hours). Since I could not figure the problem quickly and I didn't have much time, I just tried to make a fresh install of Ubuntu. Unfortunately, the problem didn't solve.

This is the logs of the last crash

syslog.1 : https://pastebin.com/raw/vBhUSR3S

The crash happened around 19.00.

New crash (5 September around 10.59): https://pastebin.com/raw/N4NmN6B8 (this is also followed by other crash during the auto-attempt to reboot, right after the bios)

Unfortunately I cannot really get what is the problem, can someone give me a hint? Or maybe addressing me to a more inherent community would still be great.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are giving us the file of the boot *after* the crash. We need /var/log/syslog.1

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro updated, what is the exact difference if I may ask? I'm sorry I just checked, they are basically the same.. is it normal?

Comment: The logs do not show any signs of why it is crashing. Is it a hard lockup or do you get a kernel oops?

Comment: The two logs seems the same. The point is that they rotate each time you boot/or each they, and you have got to find out the correct one. i.e. after crashing, syslog.1, after the next reboot, syslog.2.gz and so on.

Comment: @HostFission I'm sure it is not an oops, because it doesn't display any error log when it happens. If I get it correctly it should be an hard lockup, because for example if I'm listening to music when it happens, it loops the last half second of what I was listening for couple of seconds and then it stops completely, while no information is displayed, only black screen.. Also it happens quite often that after the crash it tries to reboot, without success for couple of attempts (same crash happens after the bios).

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I had a new crash, but only the last syslog (so just syslog) shows info about today (5 september) when the crash happened. I added it to the post.

Comment: Either I am seeing wrongly, or there are no serious errors there. I have the feeling you are not telling us the whole scenario. Virtualbox install, possibly streaming/trying to stream music via bluetooth speakers?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I don't have any bluetooth speakers. Thing is this happens even if I just turn on the pc without doing anything, and as I said in a previous comment it can also happen that right after the crash it tries to reboot and crashes again after the bios, without even booting ubuntu. I'm sorry but I'm still a newbie in this field and I don't know where to look specifically. Are there other log files where I could get more info?

Comment: A bad RAM chip can cause intermittent problems that are hard to trace. Try running a memtest to eliminate that possibility.

Comment: @PaulH. While it was performing the memtest, after 40 min (still no pass or error)  it crashed. Is it the memory then or what?

Comment: It's a good possibility. Try pulling RAM chips one (or two) at a time and see if you can get a successful test.

Comment: An oops may not always end up in the syslog, it depends on the kind of fault. For example, an oops might occur due to a disk controller failure which will prevent the syslog being written. It does look like it is a hardware fault, I would run `memtest86+` on the machine overnight to check for bad ram.

Comment: One more thing, check your fans and make sure everything is clean and working properly. Heat is another thing that can cause these kinds of problems.

Comment: @PaulH. While I was checking each ram separately for the memtest I noticed that the graphic card was really hot, and indeed the fan sometimes was not working due to the dust inside. I'll clean it and see if the problem solves.

Answer (score 0):

Okay it seems that now the problem is solved.
It was due to the fan of the gpu card that was not working correctly and hence the graphic card itself was overheating. I changed graphic card and so far I did not have any problem.

Thanks to everyone for the help!